# State management in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm working on my project which is kind of Bug tracker application. I'm using Razor Pages and jQuery, and now I need to find out **how the state of my application should be managed**. Mainly based on this [article](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/state-management) written by Mike Brind I decided to start using cache mechanism.

The plan is to load required data from DB at the initial *GET* request after user Login. User will be able to click on option from navbar, and instead of redirect to the separate page(which is equal to reloading whole page) I'd like to invoke handler method, which will render the partial view with required data by ajax call.

This is how Get handler could looks like:

```
    public async Task OnGet(int qaId)
    {
        //Initialize properties
        MyData= ctx.LoadFromDb(qaId)

        //Prepare data
        var data= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyData);

        //Store data in cache
        _cache.Set("UserData", data);
       
    }
```

Handler for navbar

```
    public ActionResult OnGetReturnSelectedView(string id)
    {
        //I know this swich statement 'smell', but it's just for presentation purpose
        switch (id)
        {
            case "dashboard":
                return new PartialViewResult()
                {
                    ViewName = "_Dashboard"
                };
            case "new":
                return new PartialViewResult()
                {
                    ViewName = "_CreateRequest"
                };
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

And AJAX call:

```
navbarOption.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get id from navbar option
    var id = this.id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/UserView/Index?handler=OnGetDashboardView",
        dateType: 'json',
        data: { 'id': id }
    }).done(function (data) {
        //replace container content with partial view returned by handler
        $('#usercontent').html(data);
    })
})
```

So my approach is to load all required data (I'm working with small number of DB records), store it in cache and write some logic to distribute this data to the partial views.

I'm not sure if it is an antipattern for razor page to rely on ajax calls rather than loading content by whole pages. Also I'd like to know *if this approach for managing state of the application is efficient*. I find it much easier to store and retrieving data from cache rather than managing state by using model bindings. I can't see why I should retrieve data from DB for every invocation of my handler, bind it to model properties etc, when I can just load whole required data at once at the beginning, and propagate it to different menu views.

I have a little experience with web, razor pages and architectural patterns, but I hope I find some advices here.

Thank you!

Comment: You can get html from ajax in razor page,it‘s common.When we want to get dynamic Partial View,we  will do like this.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer for my question. It is more important for me to understand pros and cons behind using cache mechanism vs using db queries every time when I reload my page by using razor page Get() handler.